# Qual o problema de retornar um variável local?

Tags: c++, string, variáveis

O que pode acontecer se eu retornar um variável local? Eu li na internet que não é uma boa ideia retornar uma variável local.

Talvez por que a variável quando sair da função é deletada?

Exemplo:

```
std::string StrLower(std::string str)
{
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), tolower);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Eu nunca ouvi isso, inclusive marquei a sua pergunta como favorita para caso alguém a responda, acredito que possa ser em caso de economia de memoria, projetos para arduino por exemplo que temos que economizar memoria já que ele tem um hardware mais limitado, porque se você passar a variável por referencia ela vai ocupar somente um espaço em memoria, e se retorna outra variável ela irá utilizar mais um espaço em memoria.

Comment: Eu não vejo sentido nesta afirmação e sem você colocar o contexto de onde leu tal informação, acredito que será impossível aferir qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa afirmação é velha e existe justamente pois os compiladores não sabiam otimizar o código bem antigamente, resultando em um executável com performance questionável (a variável é copiada, e cópias podem ter um custo alto). Hoje em dia, retornar algo local pode ser até melhor que usar parâmetros de saída. Claro, nunca confie em frases populares sobre otimizações, sempre faça os cálculos e medidas de performance do seu programa pra tirar qualquer conclusão.

Temos dois nomes para os tipos de otimizações possíveis nesse caso:

- **RVO: Return Value Optimization** (otimização de valor de retorno em Português), e
- **NRVO: Named Return Value Optimization** (otimização de valor de retorno com nome em Português), que basicamente é uma variação de RVO pra casos quando o valor tem um nome (i.e. é uma variável).

Essas duas técnicas de otimização estão dentro da técnica [**Copy Elision**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (elisão/omissão de cópia em Português). Em [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), elisão de cópia faz parte da padronização. Antes, essa técnica era mencionada como permitida, mas não entrava em muitos detalhes sobre quais casos eram ou não permitidos de omitir cópias.

Com tudo isso dito, agora podemos observar os efeitos de RVO e NRVO:

Quando a técnica de otimização RVO é aplicada com sucesso, a cópia (que antes seria feita) de um objeto, que acabara de ser criado e retornado pela função, é omitida, fazendo com que a área de armazenamento desse objeto seja o mesmo do objeto que está recebendo esse valor de retorno. Pra ficar mais claro, o seguinte código:

```
#include <string>

std::string foo() { return "teste"; }

auto s = foo();
```

É transformado para o seguinte:

```
#include <string>

std::string s;

void foo() { s = "teste"; }

foo();
```

Perceba como a otimização usou o armazenamento da variável de fora `s` para atribuir a string literal `"teste"`, em vez de criar uma nova `std::string` e copiar esse objeto pro `s`. Compilando com GCC 7.3 e com otimização nível 3, temos o seguinte corpo para a função `std::string foo()`:

```
foo[abi:cxx11]():
  lea rdx, [rdi+16]                    # Calcula o local onde `s` está
  mov rax, rdi
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi+16], 1953719668   # Escreve "teste" no buffer de `s`.
  mov BYTE PTR [rdi+20], 101
  mov QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 5             # Escreve o tamanho da string.
  mov QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
  mov BYTE PTR [rdi+21], 0             # Escreve o caractere nulo da string.
  ret
```

Em vez de criar um novo objeto de `std::string`, a função `foo` apenas assume que o local de armazenamento do objeto já existe (isto é, quem chamou a função já alocou espaço pro objeto) e faz uso dele.

A variação NRVO faz exatamente a mesma coisa, exceto que ela é estendida para variáveis. Se tivéssemos o seguinte código:

```
#include <string>

std::string foo()
{
    std::string s_local = "teste";
    s_local[0] = 'T';
    return s_local;
}

auto s = foo();
```

Teríamos exatamente a mesma saída otimizado, com a única adição de um `mov BYTE PTR [rdi+16], 84` no fim, que altera o primeiro caractere da string pra um T maiúsculo. Isto é, `s_local` e `s` terão o mesmo local de armazenamento após a otimização.

Existe alguns casos em que a otimização NRVO não pode ser aplicada facilmente. Se apenas retornarmos a mesma variável local, então a aplicação da NRVO é trivial. Caso contrário, se tivermos retornos de múltiplos valores, então estamos em um caso difícil para a NRVO, e provavelmente a otimização não será efetuada. Por exemplo:

```
std::string foo(bool b)
{
    std::string s1 = "abc";
    std::string s2 = "def";
    return b ? s1 : s2;
}
```

Aqui, o compilador pode até conseguir aplicar NRVO (escrevendo `"abc"` ou `"def"` na string, dependendo do valor de `b`), mas assim que o código vai ficando mais complexo, as chances de NRVO ser aplicado com sucesso diminuem. Em contraste, se apenas tivermos retornos de sempre a mesma variável, a função pode ficar o quão complexa quiser, que a aplicação de NRVO será trivial independentemente.

Por fim, aqui está a saída da sua função (brevemente alterada) de alguns compiladores (compilando com [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) em todos).

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string foo()
{
    std::string s = "teste";
    std::transform(begin(s), end(s), begin(s),
                   [](char c) { return c - 32; });
    return s;
}
```

Com GCC 7.3 e nível de otimização 3:

```
foo[abi:cxx11]():
  lea rdx, [rdi+16] # Calcula o começo da string que já existe fora da função
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi+16], 1953719668 # Escreve "teste"
  mov BYTE PTR [rdi+20], 101
  mov rax, rdi
  mov QWORD PTR [rdi+8], 5
  mov BYTE PTR [rdi+21], 0
  mov QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
  sub BYTE PTR [rdi+16], 32 # Sequência de subtração (pra passar pra maiúsculo)
  sub BYTE PTR [rdi+17], 32 # que foi desenrolado de `std::transform`
  sub BYTE PTR [rdi+18], 32
  sub BYTE PTR [rdi+19], 32
  sub BYTE PTR [rdi+20], 32
  ret
```

Com Clang 6.0.0, nível de otimização 3 e também compilando com libstdc++:

```
foo[abi:cxx11](): # @foo[abi:cxx11]()
  lea rax, [rdi + 16]
  mov qword ptr [rdi], rax
  mov qword ptr [rdi + 8], 5
  mov dword ptr [rdi + 16], 1414743380 # Clang conseguiu remover o `std::transform`
  mov word ptr [rdi + 20], 69          # e já passou a string na versão maiúscula
  mov rax, rdi
  ret
```

Você pode brincar e testar com as saídas dos compiladores no [Compiler Explorer Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/BQnLCz).

Answer (score 3):

Você nunca retorna variáveis. Isso é um conceito abstrato para facilitar o entendimento do código, mas não sendo algo concreto não podemos transpor para outro local. Portanto a variável local só existe lá mesmo e não tem como sair.

Você retorna um valor. Ok, entendo que o que queria dizer era isso. Um valor criado localmente (alocado na *stack*) só pode ser copiado, porque esse valor vive em uma área que fica garantidamente viva enquanto a função está sendo executada, depois, para todos os efeitos, considere que esta área será destruída. Se você tentar acessar o valor em sua posição original potencialmente estará acessando lixo, algo que não deve. Copiando você transporta o valor para uma área que seguramente estará viva quando você acessá-lo.

Tipos longos possuem muitos dados para transportar e acaba ficando lento. Por isso a maioria dos tipos longos são por referência.

Alguns tipos tem semântica de referência, então em vez de você retornar o valor do objeto em si você retorna uma referência para ele, então considera-se que você moveu o objeto, assim só a referência (ponteiro) é copiado, e a referência aponta para o valor efetivo. Aí que está o problema. você retornou uma referência para um valor que será destruído no final da execução da função, oque obviamente dará problema, simplificadamente falando. É disso que o pessoal fala.

Neste caso a solução é alocar no *heap* (definição no *link* acima), ou passar o valor por referência, o que permitirá escrever no local onde o valor sendo manipulado nesta função será usado na função chamadora. Assim é garantido que o valor estará vivo quando for usar.

> Talvez por que a variável quando sair da função é deletada?

Isso, embora para usar a terminologia correta eu diria que é porque o valor é potencialmente destruído ao sair da função.

Consertando os erros o código funciona perfeita (espero que seja um exemplo genérico, não acho isso uma ideia em código real):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string StrLower(string str) {
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](char c) -> char { return tolower(c); });
    return str;
}
int main() {
    cout << StrLower("TESTE");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oHTcgt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/beksbjww-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Lower.cpp).